# This tag is literally [gibberish]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I had to laugh when I saw this tag: [gibberish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gibberish)

> "Gibberish" or "gobbledygook" refer to speech or other uses of language (e.g, text) that is nonsense, or that appears to be nonsense.

There are 42 questions, of which I would be happy to handle myself. There are no common technologies with this name. It's just a meta tag that appears on questions that happen to use the word "gibberish" somewhere in the post. I think it's pretty clear this should be burninated.

Comment: Yeah, I got nothing. This tag is so ridiculous it can't be mocked any better

Comment: [Gibberish: Fast, JavaScript DSP library that creates JIT optimized audio callbacks using code generation techniques](https://github.com/charlieroberts/Gibberish)

Comment: @TinyGiant Haha, I was wondering if there might be a JavaScript library. It looks like there [haven't been any questions about it though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gibberish+javascript).

Comment: Suggested title: "fjafjkldskf7jkfdj"

Comment: I'm not sure about this. As a non-native English speaker, I did have to handle gibberish when sending Emails using wrong encoding (For example) - So I think that one may use this tag in a question when it's about encoding related issues

Comment: @Alon: you’d use the encoding tag. And that's not gibberish; you have a Mojibake (but you wouldn't have to use a tag for that either). The point is that there are no experts looking for questions on gibberish.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know that it's unlikely for anybody to add this tag as favorite, but I thought that while Googling for an answer and finding one on SO that has this tag, will allow the user to see related questions. I agree that it's always encoding related issue at the end, but new developers might not be familiar with this term (encoding) - And when they see "???? ?? ????" or other weird characters instead of the original text, they will search for a solution to the gibberish issue

Comment: @AlonEitan: 'gibberish' is not a standard term, while 'encoding' *is*.

Comment: The tag is gone (I went through the 40-odd posts, closed what was off-topic, cleaned up where needed and removed the tag everywhere).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Somebody just recreated this tag and retagged 50 questions. Can it be reverted by mods?

Comment: @VadimKotov thanks for the heads-up! I’ve rolled back those edits.